# Handle the session expired in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

How many ways we can extend the session expired time in ASP.net ?

Comment: what do u mean by page expired ?

Comment: If you are talking about the screen the user sometimes gets when they hit the back button on the browser, then there's probably not anything you can do unless you enable caching (at which point the browser will pull from the cache). That message is generated by the browser, not by ASP.NET. To verify, download fiddler and  see if there are any calls to the web server when the page expired scenario happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `Session_End` in  `Global.asax`, event is raised in the end of session

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ee255109(v=bts.10).aspx

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
        void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Code that runs when a session ends. 
            // Note: The Session_End event is raised only when the sessionstate mode
            // is set to InProc in the Web.config file. If session mode is set to StateServer 
            // or SQLServer, the event is not raised.

        }

}
```